# Spark optimized coding

Tags: pyspark, bigdata

I am newbie in pyspark. In the following ways of the writing the code:

```
1st way:
    s_df= s_df.withColumn('sum', s_df['Col1'] + s_df['Col2'] )
    s_df= s_df.withColumn('difference', s_df['Col1'] - s_df['Col2'] )

2nd way:
    s_df= ( s_df.withColumn('sum', s_df['Col1'] + s_df['Col2'])
                .withColumn('difference', s_df['Col1'] - s_df['Col2']) )
```

It is always advisable to use the second one, this has to do something with how spark works internally. Can anyone please give me a detailed reason for this?

Comment: the effect of the two snippets should be identical. It's just a difference in style

Comment: Isn't the second one works fast with  larger datasets?

Comment: they're identical. try doing `s_df.explain()` and you'll see identical query plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between those 2 "ways" as you describe it, as @mck points out, `s_df.explain()` will be the same for both cases.

I don't think there is an official or "advisable" way to write code, as Spark doesn't provide any style guidelines in its document. However, I find it's easier writing it this way (more readable and maintainable)

```py
s_df = (s_df
  .withColumn('sum', s_df['Col1'] + s_df['Col2'])
  .withColumn('difference', s_df['Col1'] - s_df['Col2'])
)
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that even though it's totally legitimate to override `s_df`, but you will lost your original dataframe which you probably will need it later.